# Why do I not find enough results with "you're interested in me"?

Tags: word-request, sentence-structure

I've tried to find the results of

> "you're interested **in me**"

or

> "you're interested **me".**

I want to use this phrase, for example, in the case where I know a girl and I want to ask her this question in meaning of, "Does it interest you to be my girlfriend?"

Comment: Are you going to ask her or to assert that it is the case? :) I believe that "Are you interested in me" is perfectly fine while "Are you interested me" is ungrammatical. Try to search for the question and you will find enough results

Comment: Adding to what @ixSci commented, it would be extremely rare to use the declarative sentence, "you are interested in me". Probably that's why you can't find enough results.

Comment: I suppose it could be "I would like to know if you're interested in me." or "I am hoping you're interested in me." even though the more common form might be a question. @ixSci

Comment: Why don't you invite her to a specific activity and see how it goes, rather than trying to figure out who might be interested in who? If she says yes, then she is at least interested in doing something with you-and that is a start.

Answer (score 3):

Writing out your example:

> **You are** interested in me.

and changing this to a question:

> **Are you** interested in me?

In your examples, the second one is incorrect. You may have trouble finding "you're interested in me" because of the abbreviation, or the fact that it would be considered self-centered at best to say someone else is interested in you.

Comment: So, it's correct and acceptable (grammatically) to say it. Is it?

Comment: Yes, Assiduous, to ask her, "Are you interested in me?" is correct and grammatically acceptable,(if you know her well) but if you don't, it would sound  a little bit rude.   It  would be  more polite if you asked her. just like ColleenV suggests.."I'd like to know if you are interested in me".